# Send the results of a java script function to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to get the results of a javascript function to send to a PHP file.So I can use it as a PHP variable.

This is the function that I want to use in the PHP file:

```
function password()
{
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;


}
```

This is a Prototype (so I'm not worried about security risks)

Thanks.

UPDATE: Could someone please show me how a could submit this as a form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use AJAX to send your value in php! :)

```
function password(){
    var text = "";
    var possible = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789";

    for( var i=0; i < 5; i++ )
        text += possible.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * possible.length));

    return text;


}

var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'http://www.yourSite.com/ajax.php');
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
            if (xhr.readyState === 4 && && xhr.status === 200) { 

                console.log(xhr.responseText);
            }
        }, false);
xhr.send('text=' + password());
```

Post send a data via form, so, we should add a `content-type`:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
```

Then in your php code: Just do this:

```
<?php echo $_POST['text']; ?>
```

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this but PHP keeps coming up with an error:           Notice: Undefined index: text
My PHP file is called register.php.

Comment: Ok, i'll make a test at my local! :)

Answer (score 0):

To send data to your PHP program (which runs on your web server), you have to make the web browser (which runs your Javascript) make a HTTP request. The most common options are

- submitting a form
- making an Ajax request

Comment: Hahaha a whole bunch of identical answers within seconds.  Gotta love easy ones

Comment: Do you have any suggestions how I could submit this as a form?

Comment: Put the form into the HTML, have a hidden field in there (`input type='hidden'`), set the value of that field to what you need to send, and then submit the form (the last two steps via JavaScript).

Answer (score 0):

You **cannot** pass your result from the javascript function to the PHP code... PHP code runs at the **server side** and javascript on the **client side**.

You have to make an [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) call and send your results that way.

Answer (score 0):

So, that function is being executed on the client, in Javascript?  And you want the results of it available in your server-side PHP?  I'd suggest fire an AJAX request, or submit a form.

Comment: Could you please show me how a could submit this as a form?

Answer (score 0):

If you are running this on a web server you should use GET, POST or Cookie method to share variable doing an HTTP request to sent them to a php script.